# Installing GCC 4.5 on Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, software-installation, gcc

The default GCC package available in the Fedora 16 repositories is `gcc-4.6`. I need to install `gcc-4.5` on my system.
I downloaded the packages from the kijo repository, but when I try to install them it shows that a newer `libstdc++4.6` is installed. If I try to uninstall `libstdc++4.6` it tries to uninstall the system itself! (Almost every package in the system).  And it would not allow me install `libstdc++4.5` along with `libstdc++4.6`.

Is there a easy way that I can install `gcc-4.5` on my system?

Comment: Why do you think that you need 4.5?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams well the build of a particular package has succeded on gcc4.5 when it is throwing up errors in gcc4.6 . I have been asked to try the build using gcc4.5.

Comment: Erroring out on a newer version of GCC usually means that the code wasn't written according to the standard in the first place.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I feel the same , but I cannot help it

Comment: Perhaps you should kick the error messages over to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) and let them have a crack at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the build errors worked out is preferable, so I hope that works out for you.

But it is possible to install alternate versions of gcc on Fedora.  Just not from packages -- you'll need the source, available from http://gcc.gnu.org/.  Look to download gcc-4.5.3.tar.gz from one of the download mirrors.

The following is modeled after some [info by Zhongliang Chen on installing gcc-4.3 on Fedora 15](http://www1.coe.neu.edu/~zhochen/resources/gcc.htm).

Download and unpack the gcc source tarball.  Make sure your Fedora 16 has the packages necessary for building:

```
yum install gcc mpfr-devel libmpc libmpc-devel glibc-devel
```

Then create a new, empty build directory and build gcc with a suffix of 45 -- you'll build compilers `gcc45` and `g++45` for example.  You might want a new, separate install directory like /usr/local/gcc45/

```
$cd PATH_TO_BUILD_DIR
$PATH_TO_SOURCE_DIR/configure --prefix=PATH_TO_INSTALL_DIR --program-suffix=45 --enable-languages=c,c++
$make
$sudo make install
```

Comment: Hey thanks. That took a while to compile but did work!

Comment: @Vamsi -- glad it helped.  Could you mark my answer as accepted, if you are satisfied with it?

Comment: after installation, I used update-alternatives to use the newly installed gcc and g++. How could I also update the libraries similarly? It seems like my program is still using the libraries of the previously installed gcc. And it seems like toolchain was built without thread support. I am also going to use threads. – Vamsi 1 min ago edit

Comment: Is this for running your program or for building your program?  For building with your gcc45, you can add some -I and -L flags pointing to your new install include and lib directories.  For running, perhaps modify your LD_LIBRARY_PATH similarly?

Comment: the messed up part is that LD_LIBRARY_PATH only has a single directory which I am sure does not have any gcc libraries.