# Installing GCC 4.6.3 on Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, software-installation, gcc

I am trying to install GCC 4.6.3 on Fedora 18.

I was following the [instructions provided by Lars Rohrbach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32240/installing-gcc-4-5-on-fedora-16).
When I run `make`, I get the error

```
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I read online that this is because of a missing library glibc, however glibc already is installed on my computer.

```
yum install glibc
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Package glibc-2.16-28.fc18.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

(Earlier I was experiencing a similar error when installing a program that required zlib and zlib also already exists.)

Can someone please help me successfully install gcc 4.6.3? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the older version of GCC?

Comment: Also, glib != glibc.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a 32-bit header. I think you want the package `glibc-devel.i686`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant glibc. I need an older version of gcc to build https://code.google.com/p/ibamr/ 
I have existing code that works only with gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: Better port the code forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7412698/1071869) at Stack Overflow:

> You're missing the 32 bit libc dev package:
>
> On **Red Hat** distros, the package name is `glibc-devel.i686`.

Probably in Fedora it's the same package name. [This](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-June/400004.html) also confirms this:

```
[root at prophead ~]# rpm --qf %{NAME}-%{ARCH}\\n -qf /usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h
glibc-devel-x86_64
[root at prophead ~]# rpm --qf %{NAME}-%{ARCH}\\n -qf /usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h
glibc-devel-i686
```